# PXListView drag and drop is not doing working

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, drag-and-drop, nsscrollview

i have created the NSViewController for managing the PXListView....delegate is connect with File owner...

here everything is working as per the expectation..except drag and drop...

while dragging it is not entering into the dragging delegate function...and it is not showing the + symbol while dragging(i.e dragging symbol)... and dragging cells relocates to its original position

```
#import "PXListView.h"

@interface ListViewController : NSViewController <PXListViewDelegate>
{
    IBOutlet  PXListView *listView;
    NSMutableArray *_listItems;

    int count;

}
- (void)addCell;

@end



- (BOOL)listView:(PXListView*)aListView writeCellsWithIndexes:(NSIndexSet*)rowIndexes toPasteboard:(NSPasteboard*)dragPasteboard
{
    // +++ Actually drag the items, not just dummy data.
    [dragPasteboard declareTypes: [NSArray arrayWithObjects: NSStringPboardType, nil] owner: self];
    [dragPasteboard setString: @"Just Testing" forType: NSStringPboardType];

    return YES;
}

- (NSDragOperation)listView:(PXListView*)aListView validateDrop:(id <NSDraggingInfo>)info proposedCell:(NSUInteger)row
      proposedDropHighlight:(PXListViewDropHighlight)dropHighlight;
{
    return NSDragOperationCopy;
}

- (BOOL)listView:(PXListView*)aListView acceptDrop:(id <NSDraggingInfo>)info row:   (NSUInteger)row dropHighlight:(PXListViewDropHighlight)dropHighlight
{
    NSLog(@"Accept Drop");

    ListViewThumbnailObject *temp = [_listItems objectAtIndex: [listView selectedCell]];
    [_listItems removeObjectAtIndex: [listView selectedCell]];
    [_listItems insertObject: temp atIndex: row];
    [listView reloadData];
    return YES;
}
```

it is not entering into the drag related delegate methods..

in the "nib" file delegate is wired with file owner...

can anyone please suggest me how to solve this problem?

Thanks,
Muthu

Answer (score 0):

To be able to accept drops, you will likely need to assure you register the list view for all dragged types you plan on accepting. Try adding this in the `awakeFromNib` method in your list view controller class:

```
- (void)awakeFromNib {
    [listView registerForDraggedTypes:[NSArray
               arrayWithObjects:NSStringPboardType, nil]];
}
```

See [Drag and Drop Programming Topics: Receiving Drag Operations](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DragandDrop/Tasks/acceptingdrags.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000993-BABHHIHC) for more info.

Note that I used `NSStringPboardType` in the array here because that's the type you declared for writing in the `listView:writeCellsWithIndexes:toPasteboard:` method. The exact array of types you use will depend on the types you want to support, and the type of drag operations you want to support (for example, do you just want to implement drag and drop to allow reordering of items in a single list view, or do you want to allow dragging items from the Finder, or to the Finder, or between different views in your own application). If you describe the type of drag operations you hope to support I can provide more details on how you might want to implement them.